# sync python code on GitHub repo and deploy on Azure function

Tags: azure, github, azure-functions, github-actions

I would like to sync the code (in an azure functions folder). I followed the doc to create a github actions cd. However in azure portal in my functions sections functions, my folder does not appear. Anyone have any idea what the problem is. I have no errors in my workflow.

I have an error when i'm trying to Redeploy/sync my code: it's not found...

[My Worflow File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YQ5oT.png)

Comment: What are the app settings in your function app?

Comment: Hi, How about the issue? Does the answer below resolved your question? If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Comment: @Vito Liu-MSFT I did the workflow as shown with the deployment slot too and my functions do not appear. Should the files be __init__.py and function.json in the folder? because it is

Comment: @MaxIvanov here are my settings https://ibb.co/mzcnxfn

Comment: I am also facing a similar issue where my github action does not updates the azure function code

Answer (score 0):

Just post how I deploy a function from GitHub repo.

My file structure:
https://github.com/Paprika-a11y/pythonfunc.git

1. Navigate to the **Deployment Center** page, configure the settings:
   [image]
2. After saving the settings, check the deployment process on GitHub Action:
   [image]
3. If your function project is correct locally, then it should appear on portal:
   [image]

If you need the workflow, here is the file generated automatically:

```
# Docs for the Azure Web Apps Deploy action: https://github.com/azure/functions-action
# More GitHub Actions for Azure: https://github.com/Azure/actions

name: Build and deploy Python project to Azure Function App - pyfunctemp

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  workflow_dispatch:

env:
  AZURE_FUNCTIONAPP_PACKAGE_PATH: '.' # set this to the path to your web app project, defaults to the repository root
  PYTHON_VERSION: '3.7' # set this to the python version to use (supports 3.6, 3.7, 3.8)

jobs:
  build-and-deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - name: 'Checkout GitHub Action'
      uses: actions/checkout@master

    - name: Setup Python ${{ env.PYTHON_VERSION }} Environment
      uses: actions/setup-python@v1
      with:
        python-version: ${{ env.PYTHON_VERSION }}

    - name: 'Resolve Project Dependencies Using Pip'
      shell: bash
      run: |
        pushd './${{ env.AZURE_FUNCTIONAPP_PACKAGE_PATH }}'
        python -m pip install --upgrade pip
        pip install -r requirements.txt --target=".python_packages/lib/site-packages"
        popd
    - name: 'Run Azure Functions Action'
      uses: Azure/functions-action@v1
      id: fa
      with:
        app-name: 'pyfunctemp'
        slot-name: 'production'
        package: ${{ env.AZURE_FUNCTIONAPP_PACKAGE_PATH }}
        publish-profile: ${{ secrets.AzureAppService_PublishProfile_xxxxxx }}
```

Comment: i have the same workflow and deployment slot, does the folder name have to be HttpTrigger1? I have in it as __init__.py and function.json file in the folder

Comment: is there another parameter to change in my function app? I also refreshed the publish profile in my function app without success.

Comment: No, the function name is customized. I will update the answer with my file structure, you could have a look. Make sure your function app run successfully on your local computer before deploy.

Comment: i have sync my repo with vs code and i add all the files missing. But it's not working. No Error on the Deployment center. (Provider Github actions with my workflow). Any other idea? nothing appear on my portal. :/ There is my repo if you would check: https://github.com/Palme240/Azure-AWS-Google

Comment: and i have an another question: .vscode is mandatory with proxies.json and host.json ?.

Comment: Where is your `function.json` file? I would update my file structure detailed, which might be more intuitive。

Comment: there is on the folder Azure_functions. It works yesterday for one hour and after the folder disappear from the portal. Very strange...

Comment: i have exactly the same repository as you and it's not working for me...

Comment: Could you check this: `https://{yourfunctionname}.scm.azurewebsites.net/wwwroot/`

Comment: i have one file... very strange https://ibb.co/VTq9N46

Comment: As you can see, your project is not published successfully to Azure. You need to publish again. Try using another way like VS Code or ftp to deploy.